# Multiple choice test in least submission attempts

Tags: combinatorics

After taking an online quiz, I started wondering about the following problem:

If I have a 10 question multiple-choice quiz (4 options) with unlimited submission attempts, what is an algorithmic approach to getting at least 80% of the questions correct in the least number of attempts? After each submission, I am given the total number of correct questions.

I am looking for an answer that gives some intuition on how to think about a problem like this.

Comment: One possible way is as follows. Submit option 1 as the answer to all the questions. Now you know how many questions have answer option 1. Now identify which of these are the correct ones. This is a standard problem in quantitative group testing. If there are $n$ questions with $d$ of them with answer as option $1$, then this can be done in $O(d \log_{d} n)$ attempts. Repeat it with option 2 and 3. You'll get answers to all the questions.

Comment: This is most likely better than checking each of the answer individually. However, I feel if all options are evenly distributed this would need $O(n)$ attempts (which is probably minimum required).